# Build and push a docker image with build arguments from DevOps to ACR

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

I'm building a docker image in an Azure DevOps pipeline, then I want to push it to the Azure Container registry. The registry is already created and I've configured DevOps to use it, also the [`buildAndPush` Docker task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/acr-template?view=azure-devops#how-we-build-your-pipeline) works.

However, since the Docker build can be parametrized, I want to pass arguments to it and [I can't do it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#task-inputs) using the `buildAndPush` Docker task. So I've decided to do it in two steps, one for building and the other one for pushing. This way:

```yml
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker
trigger: none

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaa'
  imageRepository: 'ubuntu-qt'
  containerRegistry: 'myregistry.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/docker-qt-build/Dockerfile'
  
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: BuildPush
  displayName: Build and push
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build ubuntu with qt 5.12.4 installed
      inputs:
        command: build
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        tags: 5.12.4
        arguments: '--build-arg ubuntu_version=18.04 --build-arg qt_version_major=5.12 --build-arg qt_version_full=5.12.4'
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Push ubuntu with qt 5.12.4 installed
      inputs:
        command: push
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: myregistry.azurecr.io/ubuntu-qt:5.12.4
```

Even if the build task works well, it doesn't seem to be able to find the image for pushing to the registry:

```
Starting: Push ubuntu with qt 5.12.4 installed
==============================================================================
Task         : Docker
Description  : Build or push Docker images, login or logout, or run a Docker command
Version      : 2.170.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azpipes-docker-tsg
==============================================================================
/usr/bin/docker images
/usr/bin/docker push ***/ubuntu-qt:***/ubuntu-qt:5.12.4
invalid reference format
##[error]invalid reference format
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
REPOSITORY                                           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu-qt                                            5.12.4              e5aeb1027823        2 seconds ago       6.64GB
ubuntu                                               18.04               2eb2d388e1a2        12 days ago         64.2MB
node                                                 10                  5010eb9431a5        2 weeks ago         911MB
node                                                 12                  dfbb88cfffc8        2 weeks ago         918MB
buildpack-deps                                       stretch             42d486287f16        2 weeks ago         835MB
debian                                               9                   5df937d2ac6c        2 weeks ago         101MB
debian                                               8                   72f79d3cb645        2 weeks ago         129MB
node                                                 10-alpine           8e473595b853        2 weeks ago         83.5MB
node                                                 12-alpine           057fa4cc38c2        5 weeks ago         89.3MB
jekyll/builder                                       latest              12489946feab        7 weeks ago         674MB
alpine                                               3.9                 78a2ce922f86        3 months ago        5.55MB
alpine                                               3.10                be4e4bea2c2e        3 months ago        5.58MB
alpine                                               3.8                 c8bccc0af957        6 months ago        4.41MB
ubuntu                                               14.04               6e4f1fe62ff1        7 months ago        197MB
alpine                                               3.7                 6d1ef012b567        17 months ago       4.21MB
mcr.microsoft.com/azure-pipelines/node8-typescript   latest              9a948d360778        22 months ago       595MB

    Finishing: Push ubuntu with qt 5.12.4 installed
```

Comment: Try specifying `containerRegistry` in the build step as well and use `5.12.4` for `tags` in the push step (instead of `myregistry.azurecr.io/ubuntu-qt:5.12.4`).

Comment: @h3yduck This worked, thank you. If you want to write an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @XtremeBiker, You could accept it as answer :).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Specify `containerRegistry` in the build step as well and use `5.12.4` for `tags` in the push step (instead of `myregistry.azurecr.io/ubuntu-qt:5.12.4`).

Like this:

```yaml
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build ubuntu with qt 5.12.4 installed
  inputs:
    command: build
    repository: $(imageRepository)
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
    tags: 5.12.4
    arguments: '--build-arg ubuntu_version=18.04 --build-arg qt_version_major=5.12 --build-arg qt_version_full=5.12.4'
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push ubuntu with qt 5.12.4 installed
  inputs:
    command: push
    repository: $(imageRepository)
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    tags: 5.12.4
```

Comment: As part of a migration strategy, we are building a container once and then pushing it to two different registries (DockerHub and a private Azure Container Registry). `containerRegistry` is set to 'DockerHub' in the build task, and we are getting the 'image does not exist locally' error.  Is there any way to address this short of building the container twice?

Answer (score 2):

A question was asked about how to push to multiple registries with a single build.  In order to do this you need to alias (via docker tag) the local image for each repository.

```
    steps:
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Build
        inputs:
          command: build
          repository: myimage
          dockerfile: myimage.dockerfile
          # note no containerRegistry here
          buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
          tags: latest
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: Alias registry1.io
        inputs:
          script: docker tag myimage:latest registry1.io/myimage:latest
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Push registry1.io
        inputs:
          command: push
          repository: myimage
          containerRegistry: registry1.io
          tags: latest
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: Alias registry2.io
        inputs:
          script: docker tag myimage:latest registry2.io/myimage:latest
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Push registry2.io
        inputs:
          command: push
          repository: myimage
          containerRegistry: registry2.io
          tags: latest
```

Comment: It is also possible to add the needed tags directly in the build task. It can be done using the `arguments` input with the `-t` parameter (for some reason, adding the tags using the `tags` input does not work). This removes the need for the additional CmdLine tasks.
`- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    repository: myimage
    dockerfile: myimage.dockerfile
    buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    arguments: '-t registry1.io/myimage:latest -t registry2.io/myimage:latest'`