# How to use docker build task in the Azure devops

Tags: azure, dockerfile, acr

I am trying to build a docker image through Azure DevOps  am using sample app (Node Js) to build tag and push to the azure acr, unfortunately its getting failed to find the image

In my yaml config I use AZ CLI task to tag and push the image , However its getting failed while pushing it azure acr.  below is my yaml config snippet, am i missing something?

```
Image is built using docker task 
 
 task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image
  inputs:
    command: build
    repository: azac/myapp
    Dockerfile: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile
    tags: latest

output:
REPOSITORY            TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
azac/myapp   latest      22ad073063a9   23 seconds ago   133MB
node                  18          37b4077cbd8a   12 days ago      997MB
node                  18-alpine   f520ad35ba68   12 days ago      175MB
moby/buildkit         latest      477ce8a5e273   2 weeks ago      168MB
node                  14          cedb9f0d0498   2 weeks ago      912MB
node                  16          9e98bbbbe8e1   2 weeks ago      910MB
ubuntu                20.04       61c45d0e9798   2 weeks ago      72.8MB
buildpack-deps        buster      dd092f9559e9   2 weeks ago      803MB
buildpack-deps        bullseye    7f6175124be9   2 weeks ago      834MB
ubuntu                22.04       74f2314a03de   2 weeks ago      77.8MB
debian                10          f03c282363a3   2 weeks ago      114MB
debian                11          72b624312240   2 weeks ago      124MB
ubuntu                18.04       b89fba62bc15   2 weeks ago      63.1MB
node                  16-alpine   fa7e19c4371c   3 weeks ago      117MB
node                  14-alpine   4802e63f08a5   4 weeks ago      119MB
alpine                3.14        6dff1269bc79   5 weeks ago      5.61MB
alpine                3.15        5ce65d7b0fde   5 weeks ago      5.59MB
alpine                3.16        dfd21b5a31f5   5 weeks ago      5.54MB
Login Succeeded
Error response from daemon: No such image: myapp:latest
The push refers to repository [azac.azurecr.io/myapp]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: azac.azurecr.io/myapp
```

I used some of the reference here on stack-overflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63278658/build-and-push-a-docker-image-with-build-arguments-from-devops-to-acr)

```
task: AzureCLI@2   inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'azdo Service Connetion'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      docker images
      az acr login --name azac
      docker tag   myapp azac.azurecr.io/myapp:latest
      docker push  azac.azurecr.io/myapp:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Docker@2` task you're tagging the image as `azac/myapp:latest` but in your `AzureCLI@2` task you then refer to `myapp:latest`.

I'd recommend changing your `Docker@2` task to set the repository to `azac.azurecr.io/myapp` and then your script for the `AzureCLI@2` task can just do the login and push, no tag needed.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, Now it worked , yes it was a typo , when i carefully examined i got it , however i removed the azac/myapp and replaced only with  myapp to avoid the mistake REPOSITORY       TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
myapp      latest      e6c8cfc78987   31 seconds ago   133MB

node             14          cedb9f0d0498   2 weeks ago      912MB
Login Succeeded
The push refers to repository [azac.azurecr.io/myapp]
1aaa3c14361c: Preparing